# "ImportError: cannot import name mail" in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have built is a simple web app with Flask and Python, which I intend to upload to Heroku.

When starting my app locally, with the following script:

```
#!venv/bin/python
from app import app
app.run(debug = True)
```

I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./run.py", line 2, in <module>
    from app import app, mail
File "/home/ricardo/personalSite/app/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app import index
File "/home/ricardo/personalSite/app/index.py", line 6, in <module>
    from emails import send_email
File "/home/ricardo/personalSite/app/emails.py", line 2, in <module>
    from app import app, mail
ImportError: cannot import name mail
```

So, it cannot import `mail`.

Inside the `app` directory I have this `__init__.py`, here is were I create the `Mail` object that is ginving me trouble to import:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
from app import index
from flask.ext.mail import Mail
mail = Mail(app)
```

And this is the file `emails.py` where I call the `send_mail` function:

```
from flask.ext.mail import Message
from app import app, mail
from flask import render_template
from config import ADMINS
from decorators import async
```

So, according to the error message, the error is in this file, in the `from app import app, mail`.

What is the problem? Why can't it import `mail`?

Update:

This is my directory listing:

```
persSite\
  venv\
    <virtual environment files>
  app\
    static\
    templates\
    __init__.py
    index.py
    emails.py
    decorators.oy
  tmp\
  run.py
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have a circular dependency. You have to realize what Python is doing when it imports a file.

Whenever Python imports a file, Python looks to see if the file has already started being imported before. Thus, if module A imports module B which imports module A, then Python will do the following:

- Start running module A.
- When module A tries to import module B, temporarily stop running module A, and start running module B.
- When module B then tries to import module A, then Python will NOT continue running module A to completion; instead, module B will only be able to import from module A the attributes that were already defined there before module B started running.

Here is `app/__init__.py`, which is the first file to be imported.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
from app import index # <-- See note below.
from flask.ext.mail import Mail
mail = Mail(app)
```

When this file is imported, it is just Python running the script. Any global attribute created becomes part of the attributes of the module. So, by the time you hit the third line, the attributes 'Flask' and 'app' have been defined. However, when you hit the third line, Python begins trying to import `index` from `app`. So, it starts running the `app/index.py` file.

This, of course, looks like the following:

```
from flask.ext.mail import Message
from app import app, mail # <-- Error here
from flask import render_template
from config import ADMINS
from decorators import async
```

Remember, when this Python file is being imported, you have thus far only defined `Flask` and `app` in the `app` module. Therefore, trying to import `mail` will not work.

So, you need to rearrange your code so that if `app.index` relies on an attribute in `app`, that `app` defines that attribute before attempting to import `app.index`.

Comment: Thank you for your ellaborate answer Mark Hildreth. I understand what you're saying but I don't seem to be able to rearrange my code correctly yet. I will keep working on it.

Comment: Ok. I got it now. Once again, thank you. I had never thought about how the imports work in Python.

Comment: @Xar: can you please share how you fix it?

Comment: that's the neatest explanation of imports i have read to date !

Comment: I wish I could bless this post with 10000K likes.

Comment: @Xar: share your solution, others need the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the problem:

```
from app import app, mail
```

In the file 'app/emails.py' the import is from the current module, not a nested app module. Try:

```
from . import app, mail
```

If it doesn't work, you should update your question with a more detailed directory listing.

Comment: I change the code as suggested, but it is still giving me the same error. I will update my question with my directory listing as you said.