# How is this kind of import considered circular (or why am I getting "ImportError: cannot import name EmailMessage" error)

Tags: python, python-import, circular-dependency, circular-reference

**UPDATE**:

The error (in this particular case) was not caused by circular import, but by flaw in [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) configuration. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51060856/8554766) below, for elaboration.

---

I am using:

- [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) 0.12.2
- [Python](https://www.python.org/) 3.6.1

I am building a web app using Flask, among other things I need an ability to send mails to users. I have built a separate Python module, which will be responsible for mail handling. Though I've encountered a strange (as it seems to me, at least) `import` issue, after I added the email-processing module to my app.

---

Here is the (insulated) `import` issue I've encountered:

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from test_mail import EmailTool

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Testing!'
```

**test_mail.py**

```
from email.message import EmailMessage

class EmailTool(object):
    pass
```

After launching my app and going to index (i.e. `/`) I am receiving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tmp_test_mail import EmailTool
  File "/test_mail.py", line 1, in <module>
    from email.message import EmailMessage
ImportError: cannot import name EmailMessage
```

---

I've changed code for **test_mail.py**, in order to make sure `email` module is accessible:

```
import email

class EmailTool(object):
    pass
```

This way I do not get an error.

Searching for possible causes&solutions led me to believe ([1](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky/issues/345), [2](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19466045/importerror-cannot-import-name-mail-in-flask), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894864/circular-dependency-in-python), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python)), it most likely has something to do with circular reference. Though even after reading through all the mentioned materials and insulating the problem cause, I still can not see how is it a **circular** reference. So I am concluding that either it is not circular and the cause lies in something else, or it is circular and I am missing something obvious here.

---

I am asking for help in understanding the following:

1. Is the case presented above considered to be a circular reference? (If yes, in what way it is actually **circular**)?
2. Why am I getting an error when I do `from email.message import EmailMessage` but don't get an error if I do `import email` instead?

Comment: Are you sure it is python 3.6?

Comment: no, the code above is not a circular reference

Comment: unless, of course, the `email.message` module imports from `app`, then it would be circular reference. If you could provide code from the `email.message` module that would help.

Comment: @Skilledfire, it's a part of standard library. Though, I have found the cause of the issue — see my answer below (which, by the way, contains links to the `email.message` source code =)

Comment: @hjpotter92, indeed it was the cause. Turned out my app was ran by Python 2.7.10 (see my answer below for details). Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your both of your questions:

**First**

No, the code provided above *shouldn't* be circular, unless `email.message` contains references to the `app` module, assuming `app` is a valid module.

**Second**

Importing from `email` instead of `email.message` doesn't cause any errors because you are not importing the (seemingly) problematic `EmailMessage` class since it resides in `email.message`, not `email`. My theory is that it's caused by some import looping back to the `app` module located in the `email.message` module.

## Note:

At the time of writing I was not aware that `email` or `email.message` were part of the standard (3.6.x) library, as I have never used anything related to those modules (and I don't use python 3.x< very often) and thus I assumed this was caused by **circular reference** as the author suggested. As it turns out (and pointed out in the [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51039756/8261831)) this was caused by [something else entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51060856/8261831).

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**: the actual issue had nothing to do with circular dependency — it turned out to be misconfiguration of my virtual environment (**Python version was actually 2.7.10**, as was suggested in the comment by [hjpotter92](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1190388/hjpotter92)).

---

How I found out it was the cause (posting as a collection of recipes for debugging your Python `venv`, which might later be handy for myself, and hopefully someone else):

1. Right after reading the comments to my quertion ([hjpotter92](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1190388/hjpotter92)'s comment, in particular) I've rushed to check the version of Python inside the [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) I run my app from (even though I've checked it right before posting the question — you can't be too careful in this kind of things =).


   Running (inside the virtual environment):

   ```
   python --version
   ```

   gave me (just as I have expected):

   ```
   Python 3.6.1
   ```
2. I wasn't convinced, though =). As was suggested by the this answers: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252163/printing-python-version-in-output) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093322/how-do-i-check-what-version-of-python-is-running-my-script), I have added the following to code to both modules: `app.py` and `test_mail.py` (in order to check which version of Python they are **actually ran** by):

   ```
   import sys
   ...
   print(sys.version)
   ```

   it was outputting (surprisingly for me):

   ```
   2.7.10
   ```
3. Ok, clearly something is wrong here. I have decided to refresh my basic knowledge of `virtualenv` setup. The [first article](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) I stumbled upon, suggested `pip --version` as a second step of the setup process (after `python --version`). Having nothing to loose I ran it (inside the virtual environment, of course), and (to my amazement) it gave me:

   ```
   pip 9.0.1 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
   ```

   So, somehow [`pip`](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) used inside the virtual environment was a system level one...
4. At this point I was in doubt that my app was running from `virtualenv` at all. Following the recipe from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1883251/8554766) (**and comment** to it), I have composed and added to `app.py` and `test_mail.py`, the following snippet:

   ```
   import sys

   ...

   if hasattr(sys, 'real_prefix'):
       print('Python 2 venv')
   elif (hasattr(sys, 'base_prefix') and sys.prefix != sys.base_prefix):
       print('Python 3 venv')
   else:
       print('Not venv!')
   ```

   not much a surprise (at this point) it was printing `Not venv!`.
5. To debug what exactly is wrong with current virtual environment seemed to time-costly. So, what I ended up doing:

   - removing `Flask` and related packages (`itsdangerous`, `Jinja2`, `MarkupSafe`, `Werkzeug`) from system level (which were installed there, for some reason) via `pip uninstall <package_name>`.
   - recreating virtual environment with `python3 -m venv <env_name>`

---

Now, to answer my own questions:

1. Code in my question **does not contain** a circular reference.
2. The error after trying to do `from email.message import EmailMessage`, occurred because Python 2.7.10 was actually used, and if we'll look into [source code of `message.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/468f97b4640e69b237a707a0ef9152d1c023f701/Lib/email/message.py) for this version of Python, we will see that it simply does not contain a class named `EmailMessage`. While the [source code of `message.py` for Python 3.6.* library](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/acda5ea916f4233ab90ca7b4d28af735aa962af3/Lib/email/message.py#L1159), does contain class named `EmailMessage`.

Comment: `email.message.EmailMessage` is new to python 3.6+, as can be seen from docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html which mentions: "_New in version 3.6_".

Comment: sorry for my answer, I never even new `email.message` was a built-in module.

Comment: @Skilledfire, nothing to be sorry about! We all came here to learn ;-)